# UK visa refusal because of personal loan (funds parking)

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am Indian citizen male residing in Saudi Arabia with my family.

I applied for UK visitor visa to attend a 3-day long technical training course.

The length of the visit was for 16 days, because I planned to sightsee after attending the training.

I have already visited the UK before twice. This time, I was going to the UK alone, and my family was to remain in Saudi Arabia. My family is financially dependent on me.

This visit was financially supported/sponsored by my employer, and a supporting letter was included with the application.

Given the above details, I got rejected due to not providing provenance of funds, as follows:

[image]

I had secured a personal loan in August 2016 from a bank in Saudi Arabia. My salary is deposited in the same bank account.

I had attached my account bank statements with the application. However, I did not mention the loan in the application. Also, I had not attached a separate statement from the bank about the loan, which appears as a credit on the account statement.

Is it wise to reapply?

I have approached the bank, but it refuses to provide a statement regarding the loan.

What should I do to increase the chance of succeeding with a second application? Should I attach any additional supporting document?

Is there an option for lodging complaint. Is it advisable?

Comment: Look up "funds parking".This is what they suspect you of.

Comment: They got you on funds parking like @CMaster said. I have marked your question as a duplicate because the subject is pretty well covered already.

Comment: I'll just add that if you do decide to pursue another application the bank loan story isn't going to help even if you can document it. Many people take out loans, but they generally do so to spend the money on something. Taking out a loan to leave in your bank account for a month is on its face economically nonsensical, so doing so a month before a visa application strongly suggests deceptive intent and is the very definition of "funds parking".

Comment: I am planning to pursue another visa application now i.e. 50 days after the first refusal. I am planning to submit the bank statement for last 3 months only, so as to exclude the transaction from August pertaining to personal loan which has led to the refusal. Do you think, the case officer will have access to previous history about the refusal and reason for that refusal? Do you see, submitting a Declaration Form about my loan transaction irrespectively will help?